# Data binding collection to view with Android MVVM

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding

I have been learning WPF with MVVM for a while and heard that MVVM does work on Android as well. I used to write the following in C#.

C#:

```cs
public class TodoListViewModel
{
    public List<TodoItem> todoList;
}

public class TodoItem
{
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

WPF XAML:

```xml
<ListBox Width="400" Margin="10"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=todoList}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TaskName}" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Priority}"/>
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

And wondering if there is a similar way to write in Kotlin/Android, like the following.

Kotlin:

```
class TodoListViewModel {
    var todoList: ObservableArrayList<TodoItem>
}

class TodoItem {
    var TaskName: ObservableField<String>
    var Description: ObservableField<String>
    var Priority: ObservableField<Int>
}
```

Android XML:

```xml
<LinearLayout source="@={viewModel.todoList}">
    <TextView android:text="@={TaskName}" />
    <TextView android:text="@={Description}" />
    <TextView android:text="@={Priority}" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My apologies for asking such a basic question, but I can't find any similar solution, even on StackOverflow. I can find many solutions using `Adapter` or `Factory`, but those approaches are instantiating view objects with code, and I think those are not the best way to work with XML and MVVM.

Thank you in advance for your comments and answers. It's ok for Java if you're more familiar with Java than Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach in your case is to transfer the viewmodel to your layout and then use the fields from it. I'll show you the way:

In your fragment:

```
private val viewModel = YourViewModel()
private lateinit var binding: YourLayoutBinding

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.your_layout, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.viewModel = viewModel
    }
```

In layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="pathToYourVM" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/yourText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.text}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

In ViewModel:

```
class YourViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    val text = ObservableField<String>()

    fun setText(newText: String) {
        text.set(newText)
    }
}
```

Summary:

1. Use ViewModel to manage all possible values in your Layout.
2. Fields from VM can be both common or observable fields.
3. Using bindingAdapters will discover many additional features. Read more about this https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters

p.s. don't forget to add

```
buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
```

to your build.gradle file